# Adjacency list model and substring foreign key

Tags: sql-server, database, hierarchical-data, adjacency-list

Which you think that might be the best approach to this model

we have a adjacency list model like

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM (id varchar(10), name varchar(50), parent varchar(10))
```

with the following requirement: "parent of an item must be the closest substring of id"

for example

```
id       name       parent
--------------------------
10       ItemA       null
1000     ItemB      10
10005    ItemC      1000
```

This model requires triggers to maintain data integrity

Two functions for help

```
CREATE FUNCTION fxAntecesors(@id varchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
        SELECT * FROM ITEM 
        WHERE @id LIKE id + '%' AND @id <> id
       )


CREATE FUNCTION fxParent (@id varchar(10))
RETURNS varchar(10) AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @parent varchar(10)
     SELECT @padre = MAX(id) FROM fxAntecesors(@id)
     RETURN @parent
END
```

OnInsert set the proper parent

```
CREATE TRIGGER OnItemInsert ON ITEM 
FOR INSERT AS
   UPDATE ITEM
   SET ITEM.parent = INSERTED.código
   FROM ITEM, INSERTED
   WHERE fxParent(ITEM.id) = INSERTED.id
```

OnDelete point to parent parent

```
CREATE TRIGGER OnItemDelete ON ITEM
FOR DELETE AS
   UPDATE ITEM
   SET ITEM.parent = DELETED.parent
   FROM ITEM, DELETED
   WHERE ITEM.parent = DELETED.id
```

To insert an item

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spItemInsert (@id varchar(10), @name varchar(50)) AS
   INSERT INTO ITEM (id, name, parent) VALUES (@id, @name, fxParent(@id))
```

Then for example to insert ItemD…

```
EXEC spItemInsert('100', 'ItemD')
```

the table will be as follows

```
id       name      parent
-------------------------
10       ItemA     null
100      ItemD     10       /// New Item Inserted ///
1000     ItemB     100      /// Parent updated on insert ItemD ///
10005    ItemC     1000
```

I wonder if there is a better model?

What formal norms sais about this?

thanks for your help, and hope I explained properly

---

Hogan, Thank you for your answer

But i think that with this solution we have the same problems and may be more complexity

Note that Funky_id is user relevant

```
CREATE FUNCTION fxAntecesors(@funkyid varchar(10))
 RETURN TABLE AS
 RETURN (SELECT * FROM ITEM_FUNKY_ID WHERE @funkyid LIKE funky_id + '%' AND @funkyid <> funky_id)

 CREATE FUNCTION fxParentFunkyId (@funkyid varchar(10))
 RETURNS varchar(10) AS
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @funkyparent varchar(10)
     SELECT @funkyparent = MAX(funky_id) FROM fxAntecesors(@funkyid)
     RETURN @funkyparent
 END

 CREATE FUNCTION fxParent(@funkyid varchar(10))
 RETURN int
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @parent int
     SELECT @parent = item_id FROM ITEM_FUNKY_ID WHERE funky_id = fxParentFunkyid(@funkyid)
     RETURN @parent
 END

 CREATE FUNCTION fxFunkyId(@id int)
 RETURN varchar(10)
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @funkyid varchar(10)
     SELECT @funkyid = funky_id FROM ITEM_FUNKY_ID WHERE item_id = @id
     RETURN @funkyid
 END


 CREATE PROCEDURE spItemInsert(@funkyid varchar(10), @name varchar(50)) AS
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @id int
     SELECT @id = MAX(id) FROM ITEM
     IF @id IS NULL
        SET @id = 1
     ELSE
        SET @id = @id + 1

     INSERT INTO ITEM (id, name, parent) VALUES (@id, @name, fxParent(@funkyid))

     INSERT INTO ITEM_FUNKY_ID (item_id, funky_id) VALUES (@id, @funkyid)
 END


 CREATE TRIGGER OnInsertItemFunkyId ON ITEM_FUNKY_ID
 FOR INSERT AS
 UPDATE ITEM
 SET ITEM.parent = INSERTED.item_id
 FROM ITEM, INSERTED
 WHERE fxParentFunkyId(fxFunkyId(ITEM.id)) = INSERTED.funky_id


 CREATE TRIGGER OnItemDelete ON ITEM
    FOR DELETE AS
       UPDATE ITEM
       SET ITEM.parent = DELETED.parent
       FROM ITEM, DELETED
       WHERE ITEM.parent = DELETED.id
```

In this case

```
    id     name     parent                           item_id       funky_id
------------------------------------             -------------------------------
    1     ItemA     null                              1             10
    2     ItemB      1                                2             1000
    3     ItemC      2                                3             10005


After insert new item…


   exec spItemInsert '100', 'ItemD'

   id     name     parent                           item_id       funky_id
------------------------------------             -------------------------------
    1     ItemA     null                              1             10
    2     ItemB      4 -> //Updated on Trigger//      2             1000
    3     ItemC      2                                3             10005
    4     ItemD      1                                4             100
```

i think there is no to much difference between both solutions, and the second one looks like more complex

Comment: Sorry, i don't speak english very well, i want to know if there is a better way to do this

Comment: While you have given some requirements (parent is substring), It is not clear why this would be needed.  In a typical relational database design the ID is not used as a semantic structure other than to represent a relationship.  If I had this requirement I would not store these IDs directly but instead in a related table.

Comment: "...but instead in a related table" ?

Comment: This is similar to the standard denormalization design issues. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).  This is why I keep asking why you have this requirement -- why you have the requirement is key to understanding why you have to do any of this.  There might be a better design choice.

Comment: The cause of the requirement is that at the point of view of the user, he can use funkyid or name interchangeably. Also for him exists a relation of subclassing or subcomponent between items. May even be seen as a mnemonic method for the user to know than an item is subitem or descendant other.

Comment: It may be that the only solution is removing this requirement of the data layer, but I resist it

Answer (score 0):

I made the comment.

While you have given some requirements (parent is substring), It is not clear why this would be needed. In a typical relational database design the ID is not used as a semantic structure other than to represent a relationship. If I had this requirement I would not store these IDs directly but instead in a related table.

The point of my original comment is to understand "WHY?".  Why would you want the IDs to be set up this way.  The only things I can think of is sorting and a requirement of some other component.  In both of those cases I would have other design suggestions.

However, I will answer your question in the comments and explain what I mean by "in a related table", here is an example of how to put this information in a related table.

First, your table should look in like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM (id integer, name varchar(50), parent integer)
```

Then you create the related table:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM_FUNKY_ID (item_id integer, funky_id varchar(10))
```

In this table you put a row for every id in the ITEM table.  Then add your varchar id in the second column.  Any "fixing" (eg when you delete an item) would be done in this table and only changing the funky_id column.

*One more point -- you tag your question both [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server).  Typically this is frowned at on SO.  Please chose your platform.*